# Open unit disk $D(0,1)$; its boundary covered by tiny open disks. Does the union contain a bigger disk $D(0,r); r>1$?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, complex-analysis, geometry

Recently, I met a problem which seems so trivial but hard to explain in writing:

There is an unit open disk in complex plane, $D(0,1)$, which means the center is origin and the radii is 1.  Now I put finite numbers of sufficient small open disks, $D(z_i,\delta_i)$, covering the boundary of the unit open disk, where $|z_i|=1$ and $\delta_i \ll 1$. Here is a problem:

Can I find an $r>1$ making $D(0,r)\subset D(0,1)\cup(\cup_iD(z_i,\delta_i))$?

It seems so trivial when I draw a picture on paper but hard to explain using mathematical language. Please help me and thanks very much.

Comment: Please write an *INFORMATIVE*  title... one that relates to the field and content of your question.  Your title could apply to anything, such as complex analytic sheaf cohomology.

Comment: This is unclear.  How can you have $D(0,r) \subset D(0,1)$ if $r>1$?

Comment: Hint: the function on $\{|z|=1\}$ defined by the distance to the complement of $\bigcup_i D(z_i,\delta_i)$ is continuous.

Comment: Any element of $D(z_i,\delta_i)$  will be an element of   $D(0,1 + \delta_i)$.

Comment: As you said, drawing provides the answer. It depends on how you cover the boundary with the small disks. The small disks may be tangential. This happens if their centers  are at an angle $2\arctan(\delta)$ where $\delta$ is the radius of the small disk.

Comment: But @lcv, the small disks are centered on points $z_i$ such that $|z_i|=1$. And, even without that condition, a tangential disk wouldn't cover any points on the boundary and therefore can be dropped from the consideration.

Comment: (And, also if two small disks were tangential right on the boundary $|z|=1$, the point where they touch will be covered by *neither* of them.)

Comment: Sorry the small disks intersect on just one point on the unit circle (they are not *tangential* in any sense)

Comment: @lcv The whole point is that they are *open* small disks. Still neither of them covers this point.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thank you very much for your help of editing my title!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thank you for your advice, and $D(0,r)$ is set to be a subset of the union of $D(0,1)$ and  bunch of small open disks.

Comment: Oppss I completely missed that. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stated as it it now is simple, so I suppose the problem was different, especially because of the assumption $\delta_i<1$, which is now not necessary.

**First problem**: The small open disks cover the boundary.

Denote: $K:= \bar D(0,1)$, $U:= D(0,1)\cup \bigcup_i D(z_i,\delta_i)$. Then $K$ is compact and $U$ is open and $\bar D(0,1)\subset U$. Define the function $f\colon K\to \Bbb R$, $f(x) = \mathrm{dist}(x,\Bbb C\setminus U)$. From the inclusion $K\subset U$ we know that $f>0$. Therefore from compactness it is separated from zero, i.e. $f(x)\geq \delta$ for all $x\in K$. This shows that $D(0,1+\delta)\subset U$ (why?!).

**Second problem**: The small open disks cover the interior.

This is more interesting problem and now we need the assumption $\delta_i<1$, since otherwise we could consider one ball $D(0,1)$ and the conclusion was false. Here we need to exploit the shape of big and small disks, since in the taxi metric this conslusion would also be false.

Comment: Very appreciated for your answer. About the first problem, you use that fact that the distance between a compact set and a closed set which are disjoint is strictly larger than zero, making the proof so concise and elegence, so helpful. About the second problem, I am a little confuse that whether it is different between covering the boundary and convering the interior? Intuitively, if there exists a bigger open disk $D(0,1+\delta)$ in $U$, the small open disks should be covering the boundary, or, the boundary of $D(0,1+\delta)$ will "come out" from $U$...

Comment: In the second problem the difficulty lies in the fact that we have to prove that if we have a collection of small disks that cover the interior, they must also cover the boundary. This is not true if we can consider disks of radius 1 or if we consider the square disks, like in taxi or max metric (big square can be covered by a finite family of smaller squares in a way that they don't come out of the big one).

Comment: You are right. Only covering the interior cannot guarantee the existence of such $D(0,1+\delta)$. I can draw a counter-example :D